Amazon WorkDocs End of Life
Amazon WorkDocs is coming to end of life in Apr 2025. What are alternatives for this?
We have been using WorkDocs for 2 years. We have no idea where to migrate our data.
Is AWS EFS is a good alternative?
Could you pls provide any suggestions?
AWS WorkDocs Alternatives

It all depends on how you intend to USE the files. Are you just using it for storage, or do your users need to be able to use/collaborate around the files? Tell us more about your use-case.

AWS itself has provided a migration service for getting your data off the service.
From this article here are some alternatives:


Google Workspace: Google Workspace, formerly known as G Suite, is a cloud-based productivity and collaboration platform that includes tools such as Gmail, Google Drive, Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides. It offers robust document management and collaboration features, making it an excellent alternative to Amazon WorkDocs.
Microsoft 365: Microsoft 365, formerly known as Office 365, is a cloud-based productivity and collaboration platform that includes tools such as Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneDrive. It offers robust document management and collaboration features, making it an excellent alternative to Amazon WorkDocs.
Dropbox: Dropbox is a cloud-based file hosting service that offers document management and collaboration features. It allows users to store, share, and collaborate on files in real-time, making it an excellent alternative to Amazon WorkDocs.
Box: Box is a cloud-based content management and collaboration platform that offers document management and collaboration features. It allows users to store, share, and collaborate on files in real-time, making it an excellent alternative to Amazon WorkDocs.


